# Coldfusion 10: Method is not found in component

Tags: coldfusion, components, coldfusion-10

Since we installed ColdFusion 10, we have received several error messages such as

> "Method `ifspDueDt` is not found in component `[fullpath]\incTabCnt.cfc`."

We are trying to call a method named `ifspDueDt`. It is called in one place in our entire application and when it's called, it's called from `ifsp.cfc`. We use `engine.js` for our AJAX, so the call looks like this:

`http('POST','../Components/ifsp.cfc?method=ifspDueDt', IFSPDueDtResp, param);`

We are completely baffled by the fact that for some reason and only on some occasions (certainly not all the time), ColdFusion is looking for `ifspDueDt` in `incTabCnt.cfc` instead of `ifsp.cfc`. There is no other place where this method is called. What could be causing this?

We probably get 1-2 of these errors per week, whereas we have several hundred users accessing the system.

Comment: Is `incTabCnt.cfc` referenced anywhere else in your code? It's entirely possible that you may have a malicious script that's sending posts to known CFCs. In your error reporting, what is the user agent string for the requesting client? It could be a bot or some other automated system that's hitting your bad CFC.

Comment: We *do* use incTabcnt.cfc elsewhere, but when we checked the logs, the only suspicious IP we found was for a Google bot. Unfortunately, the logs no longer go back that far, so I can't check the user agent now (do they reset when restarting CF or something?). However, in the error email, there did appear to be a valid logged-in user, but I guess I wouldn't be surprised if the malicious script could utilize that somehow. I will keep an eye out for the user agent the next time we get the error. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to find the useragent and IP from when the user logged in on the day the error occurred. Nothing looks fishy there. But I will still keep an eye out for the user agent at the time the error actually occurs.

Comment: My team appears to have a similar issue that cropped up at the point we started upgrading from CF8 to CF10.  Specifically, CF intermittently throws "method x is not found in component y" where y is the *wrong* component (or even a random CFM!).  We're looking into it...

Comment: Coincidentally, Adobe released a ColdFusion update today, and one of the resolved issues looks roughly similar: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3227975 -- the "update 3" summary is here: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-update-3.html -- we are giving it a try now.

Comment: We've since downgraded to CF9 for other reasons ("Service Temporary Unavailable", which should be fixed in Update 3), so I no longer have any logs. However, #exception.message# would give "The method incTabCnt was not found in component [...]\components\ifsp.cfc" (the wrong component) whereas the cfgi variables cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string# give us [...]/Components/incTabCnt.cfc, which is correct.

Exception.detail: Ensure that the method is defined, and that it is spelled correctly. 
Exception.templatePath: [..]\components\ifsp.cfc

Comment: It's 2023, we are on CF 2018 and we **still** get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ColdFusion 10 update 3 solves this problem, at least for the code I'm working on.  Having said that, I don't **yet** recommend upgrading, due to a series of other issues with update 3.  See the comments on the [CF blog post announcing update 3](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-update-3-released).  Note that at least two other people have posted in that comment thread that they are still experiencing the "wrong page displayed" problem, which seems like it's closely related to the "wrong component" problem we're discussing in this question.

We were fortunate that we don't use CF scheduled tasks, and we did not hit any of the startup errors or other problems in our testing environment, although one of my teammates did hit a number of problems which corrupted his dev environment.

I really hope Adobe moves quickly with update 4 (or a replacement for update 3).

Comment: "It looks like ColdFusion 10 update 3 solves this problem". It's 2023, we are on CF 2018 and we still get this error.